# Characteristics of a giant squid’s skin

Tags: evolution, zoology, marine-biology

Is the skin of a giant squid/colossal squid similar to the common squid? Does it possess chromatophores to change color? Or did it lose that ability because of the depth at which it resides or due to the comparative lack of predators?